# What is "linear" in linear entropy?

Tags: entropy

Why is the [linear entropy](https://www.quantiki.org/wiki/linear-entropy#:%7E:text=The%20linear%20entropy%20is%20a,1%E2%88%92Tr(%CF%812)), defined by $S_L = 1 - \textrm{Tr} \rho^2$, called linear?

Answer (score 8):

$S_L$ called linear because it's obtained from the usual definition of von Neumann entropy $S = -\mathrm{Tr}(\rho \ln \rho)$ by taking a [linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity#In_mathematics) approximation for the natural log $\ln \rho = \rho - 1$. Then $S_L = \mathrm{Tr}(\rho(1 - \rho)) = 1 - \mathrm{Tr}(\rho^2)$. This simplification is often useful for calculations as you can avoid having to diagonalize the density matrix. For more details, have a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purity_(quantum_mechanics)#Linear_entropy).